# Is there a way to mount Oracle DBFS on the client side?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to mount DBFS on the client side, or can it only be mounted on the database server side?

I've searched for the `dbfs_client` binary in the `Oracle Instant Client` zip, but it appears that such a binary does not exist. Does DBFS only can be mounted on Database Server? Why so many references says it is like a `nfs`? `nfs` can be mounted in any client machine.

Comment: @pmdba Could you convert your comment into an answer? This might benefit others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need to install the full client, not the Instant Client. it also requires the FUSE kernel module to mount transparently as a filesystem; that feature is available for Linux and Solaris clients only: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adlob/DBFS-file-system-access.html#GUID-6B646446-BD50-44CD-9C52-4B1039242910